# Listening for Done doesn't close soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have added a `setOnEditorActionListener` for my `EditText` so I can catch press of "Done" button. While it works like you can see in the code below and enters the `if()` section, keyboard stays open and doesn't close.

What do I have to change so I can still catch the press of "Done" button and close the keyboard ?

```
    etCompany.setOnEditorActionListener(new BackEventEditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                ((GetStartedActivity) getActivity()).isKeyboardOpen = false;
                setVisibleContent();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try this one : `<EditText
    ...
    android:imeOptions="actionDone" />`

Answer (score 1):

You can force close it with

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(textView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```